# if statement to check http status of get request AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi i'm trying to get the status of an http request and conditionally set a variable. I'm making a subcall to check if user1 is following user2. My code looks like this. (for brevity i cut the foreach function that needs to loop through a list of users that i have previously get requested reason why i have to push)

```
$scope.users = [];
  var getUser = function(id) {
        UserService.GetUserById(id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
        .success(function (data) {

         data = angular.fromJson(data);

//data model ==> {id: 0, username: "foo"}

//check if 404 or 200 ==> UserService.GetUserFollowers($stateParams.id, data.id)
//if 200 data.is_following = 1; if 404 data.is_following = 0

         $scope.users.push(data);  

//data model after pushed ==> {id: 0, username: "foo", is_following: 1}

         console.log(angular.toJson($scope.users));

        }).error(function(error, status) {
            alert(status);
            console.log(error);         
        });

    };
```

---

Tried this didn't work

```
$scope.users = [];
  var getUser = function(id) {
        UserService.GetUserById(id, $localStorage.CurrentUser.auth_token)
        .success(function (data) {

         $scope.data = angular.fromJson(data);

         UserService.GetUserFollowers($stateParams.id, $scope.data.id, -1, -1)
            .success(function(data, status) {                      
              $scope.status = status;
            }).error(function(data, status) {               
              $scope.status = status;
            });

       if ($scope.status === 200) {
          $scope.data.is_following = true;
       }else{
          $scope.data.is_following = false;
       }

        $scope.users.push($scope.data);

         console.log(angular.toJson($scope.users));

        }).error(function(error, status) {
            alert(status);
            console.log(error);         
        });

    };
```

this is my service:

```
  this.GetUserFollowers = function (my_id, to_id, begin, end) {
            return $http.get($rootScope.endPoint + '/user/' + my_id + '/followers/' + to_id + '/' + begin + '/' + end + '/');    
        };
```

!NOTE - begin and End are ignored if to_id is not -1

Comment: are you asking how to write the `GetUserFollowers` function so that it returns these status codes?  If that is the function that you are trying to work out the logic for, it would be helpful to see the code you have for it now....

Comment: @Claies check edit.. the edited code for some reason sets it true or false wrongly

Comment: what, like the status from your `$http` call comes back something other than `HTTP 200` and `$scope.data.is_following` still ends up true somehow?

Answer (score 3):

`$http` returns status code as the second argument.

```
$http.get(url)
  .success(function(data, status) {
      alert(status); // HTTP status code of the response
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
      alert('Error with status code: ' + status); 
  });
```

However, if the status is an error status, such as 404, then the `error` block will be called.

Comment: `.success` and `.error` are deprecated and not available in Angular 1.6 anymore.